# Do Sephardim observe any of the pre-Tisha B'av customs when the observance of Tish'a B'Av is postponed?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, nine-days

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three_Weeks) states:

> The last nine days of the three weeks—which are also the first nine
>   days of the month of Av, culminating in the Tisha B'Av fast—constitute
>   therefore a period of intensified mourning in the Ashkenazic custom.
>   Many Jewish communities refrain from partaking of poultry, red meat,
>   and wine; from wearing freshly laundered clothes; and from warm baths.
>   Sephardim observe many of these restrictions only from the Sunday
>   before Tisha B'Av, **dispensing with them entirely in years when Tisha
>   B'Av falls on a Sunday**.

Rarely does the actual calendar date of Tish'a B'Av occur on Sunday. More often, as this year, 9 Av is on Shabbat and the observance of Tish'a B'Av is on SUnday which is 10 Av. Does this mean that Sephardim **do** observe the mourning laws beginning from the previous Sunday (which would be starting from 3 Av), or does it mean that they don't observe the mourning rules?

Comment: Posted my answer while misreading this question to be about the case where 9 Av itself is on Sunday. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

The Shulchan Aruch ([551:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&pgnum=51)) rules regarding both the case of Tisha b'Av on Saturday *and* Tisha b'Av on Sunday that there is no mourning period and some say (Yesh Omrim) that there is mourning the entire preceding week. Generally when the Shulchan Aruch quotes two opinions and only the latter is prefaced by 'some say', the halacha follows the former opinion ([Yad Malachai Klalei HaShulchan Aruch 17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14122&pgnum=416)).

The Kaf haChaim ([sk 78](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14424&st=&pgnum=208)) rules as such, but notes that it is proper to be stringent only regarding haircuts for either the entire preceding week or at least just the Friday before in order to not enter Tisha b'Av looking too nice.